# Can't able to edit Dialar screen as per my wish

Tags: java, android

I would like to define a button which on click automatically opens a dialer dialog. The dialer dialog should show **#07# but it is showing only '*'. I don't have any reason why # and the remaining characters are not shown.

My code is

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*#07#"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Please let me know how can i do the same thing and what is the reason behind the '#' problem.

Comment: It should show *#07#

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the number:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
String number = Uri.encode("*#07#");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActivity(intent);
```